# get scroll position in a container

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to do a animated svg, and I need to know the scroll position on my div, I already had some code before that I copied from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scrolldrawing.asp)

The thing is that I want the scroll to start count when it enters my div element, here is the code that i did:

```
var scrollpercent =
 (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / 
 (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);


 console.log($(".svg-container").scrollTop())
```

tried the `svg-container.scrollTop()` but it always gives me 0

Comment: Could you maybe provide us some live exmaple using JSFiddle or something similar?

Answer (score -3):

Getting scroll positions can be frustrating sometimes. If you need to know the position of an element on the screen, you can use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

```
// rect is a DOMRect object with eight properties: left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height
var rect = $(".svg-container")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```